# How to match this string?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I would like to match this string using `re.fullmatch` but I can't get it right:

```
job_string = "jobList.append(job('10-10-2022 11:12:00', 'python3 /toz/gadu/luno/getalarm.py'))"
```

The match has to be more general for cases like this:

```
"jobList.append(job('..', '..'))"
```

So far, I,ve tried those solutions but none of them match:

```
    match = re.fullmatch(
        "jobList\.append\(job\(['\"](.*)['\"], ['\"](.*)['\"],(.*)\)\)", job
    )
    match2 = re.fullmatch(
        "joblist\.append\(job\(['\"](.*)['\"],['\"](.*)['\"],(.*)\)\)", job
    )
  -
    match3 = re.fullmatch(
        "joblist\.append\(job\(['\"](.*)['\"],['\"](.*)['\"]\)\)", job
    )
    match4 = re.fullmatch(
        "joblist\.append\(job\(['\"](.*)['\"], ['\"](.*)['\"]\)\)", job
    )
    match5 = re.fullmatch(
        "joblist\.append\(job\(['\"](.*)['\"], ['\"](.*)['\"]\)\)", job
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two mistakes:

1. You're not accounting for the possible whitespace after the comma
2. The match is case senstive. So `joblist` won't match `jobList`. Use the flag `re.IGNORECASE`

```
import re

job_string = "jobList.append(job('10-10-2022 11:12:00', 'python3 /toz/gadu/luno/getalarm.py'))"

m = re.fullmatch(
        r"joblist\.append\(job\(['\"].*?['\"],\s*['\"].*?['\"]\)\)", job_string, re.IGNORECASE
    )

print(m)
```

Edit: if you want to support single (resp. double) quotes insides double (resp. single) quotes, use backreferences:

```
r"joblist\.append\(job\(('|\").*?\1,\s*('|\").*?\2\)\)"
```